# adding radial gradient to heightmap results in jagged edges

Tags: c++, heightmap, map-editor

I am trying to implement a simple heightmap editor. In this editor, you can elevate the terrain by clicking on a spot in the heightmap, and holding down the mouse button. This will little by little, every frame, elevate the terrain into a hillshape. The hills created looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2niF.jpg

As can be observed, however, the edges of the hill has some pretty awful jagged edges:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D84he.jpg

I am not quite sure how to get rid of these edges. For every frame that I hold down the mouse, the following code is executed:

```
float rad = 35;
for(int ix = -rad; ix <= +rad; ++ix) {

    for(int iz = -rad; iz <= +rad; ++iz) {

    // distance from center of hill.
    float dist = sqrt( (float)ix * (float)ix + (float)iz * (float)iz  );

    // if within the radius of the hill(this ensures that the hill is round)
    if(dist <= rad) {

        // the farther we get from the center, the less we increase the height.
        // this effectively results in a radial gradient being added to the
        // heightmap.
        // Note that we use "x*x" instead of "x", because this results in a
        // more round and natural-looking hill
        float x = dist / rad;
        float y = (1.0 - x*x);

        // maximum height of the hill
        float maxHeight =y * (float)MAX_HEIGHT;

        /*
          Note that cx and cz describe the center position of the hill.
         */

        if( heightData(cx+ix,cz+iz) < (float)MAX_HEIGHT) { // do not exceed the maximum height

             // if we hold down the mouse for 30 frames, the hill will reach its maximum height
             float increment = maxHeight  / 30.0;

            if(heightData(cx+ix,cz+iz) + increment > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                 // clamp the hill height so that it does not exceed the maximum height of the
                // height map.
                heightData(cx+ix,cz+iz) = MAX_HEIGHT;
            } else {
            heightData(cx+ix,cz+iz) += increment;
            }
        }


    }


    } // end for
} // end for
```

As can be observed, every frame I simply add a radial gradient to the heightmap. `MAX_HEIGHT = 65535;`, because the heightmap is a grid of unsigned shorts. And the resolution of the heightmap is 256x256. But even if I increased it to 512x512, the jaggies still remained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of your artifact is likely the harsh cutoff at `rad`. As you accumulate elevation, the boundary gets very discontinuous.

As for solutions, I would recommend a slightly wider filter that tends toward zero outside the desired action radius, or shrink the current filter to avoid missing grid cells that are at the boundary.

Comment: Yes, if I start interpolating towards zero near the radius, the problem is solved. If, in the original code, after the line `float y = (1.0 - x*x);` I add `if(dist > fade_rad) { y *=  (1.0f- (dist - fade_rad  ) /  (rad-fade_rad) );  }`, then it looks much better. Where `fade_rad=30`, and it is the radius at which we start interpolating. Thanks for the help!